# isFinishing method

Tags: android

`isFinishing()` method allows to check if `finish()` method was called or if the `Activity` is killed by the system.

What's the purpose of distinguishing these two scenarios?

What's the difference between calling `finish()` and killing the `Activity` by system?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the wording is: ([Source link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Activity#isFinishing()))

> Check to see whether this activity is in the process of finishing,
> either because you called finish() on it or someone else has requested
> that it finished.

It is just stating there are two different scenarios that will cause your application to go into the `"finishing" state.

1. You cause it
2. Or someone else causes it

Or, i am not understanding your question. (likely)

Comment: I don't understand difference between killing activity by the system and by calling finish() method.
In these two scenarios onDestroy() is called and activity is killed.

Comment: If the activity is calling `finish()` it is because the `Activity` is wanting to finish, for whatever reason. If the system is calling `finish()`, it is because it needs to finish the `Activity` or `Service` because of memory issues or some other failure.

Comment: I found that the OS doesn't kill single activity. It only kills processes (all activities of a process).

Answer (score 2):

> Difference between calling finish() and activity being killed

You call `finish()` when the activity is done and should be closed.

Your activity will be killed by Android (system) when the user switches to a different app and thus your activity needs to be killed.